# Tunneling in networks

Tags: networking, tunneling

I just started learning networking and encountered such notions as "tunneling" and "tunneling protocol". I can't comprehend the "motivation" of tunneling. As tunneling doesn't necessarily include encryption then what is it even used for?

3 questions:

1. What would we not able to do if there wouldn't be such things as "tunnel", "tunneling"?
2. What is a tunnel?
3. Tunneling involves exactly 3 protocols: transport protocol, carrier protocol, passenger protocol. Which of them is the tunneling protocol?

Answer (score 0):

A tunnel gives you the opportunity to leverage an existing connection between service provider(s) links rather than acquiring a dedicated line(lease) for your organisation.
It is more like creating a leased line. You could then route your traffic using private addresses which are not possible over the internet. So basically the service providers will not see the private addresses. It is a VPN. But don't forget that the fact that you are in a tunnel doesn't mean you are covered. It only means not everyone can see you, that is why you need to encrypt it.

Comment: For example, I don't have to use tunnel to get to some website(e.g. YouTube) from any PC on my NATted home network.

Comment: For example, I don't have to use tunnel to get to some website(e.g. YouTube) from any PC on my NATted home network. Also my aunt lives 10 km off from me. Her router's external IP address is a static public IP address. Can't any my PC from my network communicate with any PC on her network using appropriate port forwarding on her router WITHOUT TUNNELING? What would change if I would use tunneling without encryption for this?